# Message driven Bean failing during deployment on WebLogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, weblogic12c, ear, wildfly-11

we have a J2EE application which can be deployed on weblogic and wildfly application servers. We have a requirement of adding a message driven bean but it is failing on weblogic with below error :

```
Caused by: com.bea.xml.XmlException: weblogic.descriptor.BeanAlreadyExistsException: weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.ActivationConfigBeanImpl@604422f7(//[SampleMDB]/ActivationConfig) has already been created
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:54)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingType$BeanRuntimeProperty.setValue(RuntimeBindingType.java:541)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.MultiIntermediary.setValue(MultiIntermediary.java:81)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ByNameRuntimeBindingType$ElementQNameProperty.fill(ByNameRuntimeBindingType.java:355)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.LiteralUnmarshalResult.extractAndFillElementProp(LiteralUnmarshalResult.java:159)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ByNameUnmarshaller.deserializeContents(ByNameUnmarshaller.java:67)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeUnmarshaller.unmarshalIntoIntermediary(AttributeUnmarshaller.java:47)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.LiteralUnmarshalResult.unmarshalElementProperty(LiteralUnmarshalResult.java:184)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.LiteralUnmarshalResult.extractAndFillElementProp(LiteralUnmarshalResult.java:157)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ByNameUnmarshaller.deserializeContents(ByNameUnmarshaller.java:67)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeUnmarshaller.unmarshalIntoIntermediary(AttributeUnmarshaller.java:47)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.LiteralUnmarshalResult.unmarshalElementProperty(LiteralUnmarshalResult.java:184)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.LiteralUnmarshalResult.extractAndFillElementProp(LiteralUnmarshalResult.java:157)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.ByNameUnmarshaller.deserializeContents(ByNameUnmarshaller.java:67)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeUnmarshaller.unmarshalIntoIntermediary(AttributeUnmarshaller.java:47)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalBindingType(UnmarshalResult.java:199)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshalResult.java:169)
at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:67)
at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:155)
... 139 more
```

Below are the details from the descriptor files:
ejb-jar.xml

```
<message-driven>
    <ejb-name>SampleMDB</ejb-name>
    <ejb-class>com.test.SampleBean</ejb-class>
    <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    <activation-config>
        <activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
            <activation-config-property-value>test.queue</activation-config-property-value>
    </activation-config-property>
    </activation-config>
    <message-driven-destination>
        <destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</destination-type>
    </message-driven-destination>
</message-driven>
```

There is nothing in the app server specific descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is your current Weblogic version number
2. Start up provides the corresponding server.log journal
3. Please check the web.xml Check whether mapping, taglib or other definitions are repeated according to the error message.

Comment: Weblogic current version is 12.2.1.3 & wildfly current version is 11

Comment: There is no any repeated mapping and definitions present in web.xml

Comment: Start up provides the corresponding server.log journal

Answer (score 0):

Please check the web.xml Check whether mapping, taglib or other definitions are repeated according to the error message.